# Determine width of UIView in Swift

Tags: swift, uiview

I have an autolayouted `UIView` and need to know the width of it. How do I find the width the easiest way in Swift?

Comment: `view.bounds.size.width`...?

Answer (score 6):

You can find the width of any view by

```
 let width = yourView.bounds.width
```

If you have applied a width constraint to the view and you have an outlet for that constraint then you can find it by.

```
let width = yourWidthConstraint.constant
```

Comment: This is the answer. It's simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

The right place to get the UIScreen frame data is in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` as it is called after the `subViews` have been laid out in screen also it is called after every time your device changes orientation such as your width will be different when your user goes into landscape mode.This is called after `viewWillAppear`:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let viewWidth = self.myView.bounds.width

  }
```

Comment: This helped me a lot bro. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Inside implementation your view you can use

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    // you can get width of view in this function
    print(self.frame.size.width)
}
```

Comment: Does your code really has the answer to the question?

Comment: I think I answer exactly he want ! so do you devote me ?

Comment: I have added an image to my question to try and clarify what distance I am looking for. I have added an `UIView` to `Main.storyboard`. It is the width of that `UIView` I want.

Comment: Working like a charm